# Read data from file that has a string with each line and may or may not have an integer with it

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have a project where we read data in from a file and use the commands to organize the data in a stack or queue depending on what the data wants us to do. How would I read this information from a file properly and make it work in a `class`? I know how to set up a `class`, I just need to know how to make this work? I'm not going to provide my classes because I know how to set them up, I only would like to know how to read in information that has a string with an integer and a `string` by itself.

Here's a sample of what's in the file:

```
// push 20
// push 20
// pop (this line causes it to repeat indefinitely)
// push 50
// pop
// pop
```

Here's my code:

```
int main ()
{
    int value = 0;
    string commandname = " ";
    string input = " ";
    ifstream readfromfile;
    string push = "push";
    string pop = "pop";
    string append = "append";
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: \n";
    cout << "(remember to put .txt at the end of the file name) \n";
    cin >> input;
    readfromfile.open (input);
    if (!readfromfile)
    {
        cout << "File does not exist. Please check the name of the file and try again.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File successfully opened!\n";
        do
        {
            if (readfromfile >> commandname >> value) //Here's where I think the problem is because some lines have an integer and some don't and I want to figure out how to do that.
            {
                if (commandname == "push")
                {
                    push (value);
                }
                else if (commandname == "pop")
                {
                    pop (value);
                }
                else if (commandname == "append")
                {
                    append (value);
                }
            }
        } while (!readfromfile.eof ());
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hope `string push = "push";` this is what you wanted to say not `string push = push`.

Comment: How are we supposed to know how it would work in a class if you don't show us how you've implemented it. There are many ways to use a class to read input. The best thing you can do is show us what you've tried so we can point out where you've gone wrong. From here I can see that you're reading into `value` even if an integer didn't appear after the first command. The stream will go into a fail state, thus causing an infinite loop because your stop condition `!eof()` is never met.

Comment: Because the classes are not a problem. I can set up the class just fine. Reading from the file does not involve the classes. It's in the main function. I don't care about the classes right now, I only want to know how to have the program read it in so it doesn't go into a fail state and an infinite loop. How would I set the program up to read each line which all have strings some integers and handle them? What's the correct if, else if, or else statements needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but here's an idea:

```
while(!readFromFile.eof()) {
    readFromFile >> commandname;
    if (commandname == pop) {
        // pop
    }
    else if (commandname == push) {
        readFromFile >> value;
        // push value
    }
}
```

Not sure what append does, but you get the idea. Hope this helps